# Refresh the drop down list in a ASPX file when a button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list that contain dynamic information as follows inside a ASPX file:

```
Select the item: <select id="DropDownList1"><option>Select Here</option></select>
```

There is a button that will update the item been modified as follows:

```
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Update item" />
```

How do I only refresh the drop down list with the latest information when the button is clicked?

Comment: none of your elements have the runat="server" attribute. Intentional?

Comment: @PenchoIlchev, wait a minute, you mean that I need to have the `runat="server"` for all my DropDownList and Button? That's strange cause it can still run without the `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use ASP.NET Web server control instead of HTML markup. Add `<asp:DropDownList/>` and `<asp:Button/>` controls in your web-form and handle click event of Button control where you may add items into dropdownlist.

EDIT: You may populate the `<select>` using jQuery/JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#submit").click(function () {
         var items =
         [
            { "key": "1", "value": "One" },
            { "key": "2", "value": "Two" }
         ];
         $("#DropDownList1").html("<option>Select Here</option>");
         for (i in items) {
             var item = $("<option>");
             item.attr("value", items[i].key);
             item.text(items[i].value);
             item.appendTo($("#DropDownList1"));
         }

     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi AVD, is it possible to provide more information with regards to the `handle click event of Button control`? Currently, what happen was that I have a `$("#submit").click(function() { CreateNewItem(); window.location.reload(); });` ==> which will refresh the whole page. What I wish for is to update just the dropdownlist only and I do not wish to add C# or VB code inside. I just wish to have only ASPX code and JQuery code inside my ASPX file.